# Spam e-mail tracing

Tags: ubuntu, email, spam

I have this issue where I receive on my server admin e-mail failure notices to a lot of e-mails that I or my hosted domains did not send.

The machine is an Ubuntu with Plesk 11. For e-mail I use qmail, which is the standard this server has.

Every user is allowed to send e-mail based on SMTP authentication. However some e-mails did get past that.

Here is a header from such an e-mail which I cannot trace to its origin (the pipe through which it is coming)

```
Received: (qmail 13781 invoked from network); 28 Apr 2014 17:15:42 +0300
Received: from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (HELO User) (XXXXXX)
  by XXXXXX with ESMTPA; 28 Apr 2014 17:15:41 +0300
Reply-To: someemail
From: someemail
Subject: some spam email subject
Date: Mon, 28 Apr 2014 16:15:41 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00E5_01C2A75B.10F0C4E2"
X-Priority: 1
X-MSMail-Priority: High
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 5.50.4522.1200
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V5.50.4522.1200
```

What I can trace from this header is that the user sent the e-mail using Outlook express and authenticating with ***ESMTPA***. The problem is that I do not know how to trace it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your user has a compromised machine that is sending spam through your server.  You can probably verify this by looking in the mail logs (there will be a *lot* of email) or using `tcpdump -n port 25` to verify the content.

It's probably worth running Spamassassin on your outbound email to prevent this sort of thing before it happens or at least detect it and alert you.